# View collections item in Mern

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, collections

I have some items in a **mongodb collection**, now i want to view them on a react app, i've that code, but **it doesn't display nothing**, but if i check **value** with a console.log() **i get the content**. How i can do?

````
import axios from "axios";

const viewMails = []

axios.get('http://localhost:5000/emails').then(res => {

    let emailString =  JSON.parse(res.request.response)

    for (const [index, value] of Array(emailString).entries()) {
        viewMails.push(
            <div key={index}>
                <h1>{value.name}</h1>
                <h3>{value.email}</h3>
                <p>{value.message}</p>
                <p>{value.createdAt}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

export default class EmailsViewer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="emails">
            <h1>Sos</h1>
            {viewMails}
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to do a simple component to show a list, if you're using one of the last version of React, consider using axios hook (check the package documentation to see how to add it to your project https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hook)

Here I show you an example of what you need to do: [list demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-hooks-quick-start-08tuf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)